# Create Data Entry Window with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a complete novice when it comes to using Tkinter. I would like to create a function that pops up a window from the main one and asks a user to input some data. They will then click ok and the data will be returned.

The problem I'm having is that I want the my function to pause until this OK button is pressed so it will actually return values instead of empty strings. So far I have the code below.

```
def enterData(self, *arg):
    top = self.top = Toplevel(self)
    top.title("Data Entry")
    label = []
    self.entry = []
    for i in range(0, len(arg)):
        label.append(Label(top, text=arg[i]))
        label[-1].grid(row=i, column=0)
        self.entry.append(Entry(top))
        self.entry[-1].grid(row=i, column=1)

    ok = Button(top, text ="Ok", command = ??Pause??)
    ok.grid(row = len(arg), column =0)
```

Comment: Could you provide a more complete example of the code? I can't see what enterData is bound to. It may be a case of the entry being called on each character entry (or possibly some other event) and so you might need to accumulate these characters in a list and return that on pressing of the button.

Comment: So my code would run a button command1 say and I wanted this command to pause and prompt the user to enter data before continuing to run. In the console I would just have used `raw_input()'. But with Tkinter I couldn't get it to do this.

Instead I've just made a button prompting the user to enter data before command1 is run. Hopefully that makes sense.

I'm not sure whether to delete the question?!

Comment: If you've solved your problem, you can post your answer so future readers can benefit from it, but as it stands, they'd lack some of the context to understand the solution.

Comment: Unfortunately what I've done is more of a workaround than a solution to the problem. I'll see if I can edit the explanation to make it clearer.